# OutofScope getters c++?

Tags: c++, scope, getter

I'm trying to use the ostringstream class but when I call the getter methods, I get an error saying:  error: getQuantity was not declared in this scope

This is what I have in my .h file

```
public:
const std::string &  getName() const;
int getQuantity();
std::string listInfo();

private:
std::string name;
int quantity;
```

This is what I have in my .cpp file

```
ostringstream outputString;
const string & Product::getName() const
{
return name;
}
int Product::getQuantity()
{
return quantity;
}
string listInfo()
{

outputString << getName() << getQuantity();
return outputString.str();
}
```

I don't understand how it's out of scope if it's in the same file? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You meant to write

```
string Product::listInfo()
```

instead of

```
string listInfo()
```

The latter declares a free function which has no knowledge of `getQuantity()` at namespace scope (because `getQuantity` is a member function).

Scope has little to do with which file you're in. The following variables are different in scopes on the same line:

```
{int x;}{int x;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
string listInfo()
{

outputString << getName() << getQuantity();
return outputString.str();
}
```

is definition of a non-member function of a class. You forget to specify class name before the function name.

There should be

```
string Product::listInfo()
{

outputString << getName() << getQuantity();
return outputString.str();
}
```

Also it is a bad idea that you defined `outputString` as a globale variable that is used by the member function listInfo

```
ostringstream outputString;
```

It would be better that it were either a static data member of the class or a local variable of the function. Also this function could be declared with qualifier const. For example

```
string Product::listInfo() const
{
ostringstream outputString;
outputString << getName() << getQuantity();
return outputString.str();
}
```